# AngularJS & Ionic: Two Objects in one Scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular / Ionic and have a short question. Is it possible to put two Objects in one scope? Like this:

```
$scope.Lorem = [
    { title: 'Ipsum', 
      text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr', 
      cards: [{
                title_cards: 'Title1',
                desc_cards: 'desc1',
            },
            {
                title_cards: 'Title2',
                desc_cards: 'desc3',
            }
        ]},
        ];
```

If yes: How can I get the data from "cards"? If no: Is there any other possibility to "connect" a scope with an object from another one?

Hope you can help me! Thanks.

Comment: I see only one big object on the scope. You can however have 2 different objects on the same scope.

Comment: @CédricDourin you can put whatever json object you want into a scope variable. Inside one json object you can nest other json objects. What you have in `$scope.Lorem` is an **array**.

Answer (score 0):

You can get cards by using $scope.Lorem.cards[x].* Where x is the index of the object you want to access and * is the key you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

hoping that the below is your requirement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>{{Lorem[0].title}}</div>
     <div>{{Lorem[0].text}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="x in Lorem[0].cards">
    <p>{{x.title_cards}}</p>
    <p>{{x.desc_cards}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.Lorem = [
    { title: 'Ipsum', 
      text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr', 
      cards: [{
                title_cards: 'Title1',
                desc_cards: 'desc1',
            },
            {
                title_cards: 'Title2',
                desc_cards: 'desc3',
            }
        ]},
        ];
        
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like normal object

`$scope.Lorem[0].cards[0].title_cards` in js and `Lorem[0].cards[0].title_cards`in html.